# Sonar LE freezes when using MME (32-bit) driver mode

Tags: audio-recording, audio, daw

A few days ago I started having problems with Sonar in MME driver mode. Basically it freezes when I try to execute the most trivial operations, such as arming a track for recording. It had worked fine until then. I can switch over to other driver modes to make the lag go away, but then my recordings contain clicking sounds.

How can I find the root of the problem? I already tried updating my sound drivers.

**Edit**: the clicking sounds I hear are a playback issue, not a recording issue. If I export my project, it sounds fine.